# extension context does not have a method

Tags: c++, apache-flex, actionscript, air, native

I am trying to build a native extension written in C++ for an adobe flex project. I double checked everything a hundred times but whatever I do I always get the error "The extension context does not have a method with the name getHelloWorld".

This is my code:

Flash builder actionscript class:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.external.ExtensionContext;

    public class QCARBridge extends EventDispatcher
    {
        private var extContext:ExtensionContext;

        public function QCARBridge()
        {
            extContext = ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext("NativeQCAR", null);

            if(!extContext) {
                throw new Error("Extension context couldn't be created :(");
            }
        }

        // Native methods
        public function getTestString():String {
            return extContext.call("getTestString") as String;
        }

        public function isSupported():int {
            return extContext.call("isSupported") as int;
        }

        public function getHelloWorld():String {
            return extContext.call("getHelloWorld") as String;
        }
    }
}
```

Flash builder extension.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extension xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.1">
    <id>NativeQCAR</id>
    <versionNumber>1</versionNumber>
    <platforms>
        <platform name="Windows-x86">
            <applicationDeployment>
                <nativeLibrary>libNativeQCAR.dll</nativeLibrary>
                <initializer>initializer</initializer>
                <finalizer>finalizer</finalizer>
            </applicationDeployment>
        </platform>
    </platforms>
</extension>
```

and the c++ code:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "Stdlib.h"
#include "String.h"

FREObject isSupported(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
{
  FREObject result;

  uint32_t isSupportedInThisOS = 1;

  FRENewObjectFromBool( isSupportedInThisOS,  &result);

  return result;
}

FREObject getTestString(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
{
  FREObject result;

  const char *str = "De android library zegt ook eens hallo...";
  FRENewObjectFromUTF8(strlen(str)+1, (const uint8_t *)str, &result);

  return result;
}

FREObject getHelloWorld(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
{
  FREObject result;

  const char *str = "Hello World!!  This is your DLL talking!";
  FRENewObjectFromUTF8(strlen(str)+1, (const uint8_t *)str, &result);

  return result;
}

void contextInitializer(void* extData, const uint8_t* ctxType, FREContext ctx, uint32_t* numFunctions, const FRENamedFunction** functions)
{
  *numFunctions = 3;
  FRENamedFunction* func = (FRENamedFunction*) malloc(sizeof(FRENamedFunction) * (*numFunctions));

  func[0].name = (const uint8_t*) "getTestString";
  func[0].functionData = NULL;
  func[0].function = &getTestString;

  func[1].name = (const uint8_t*) "isSupported";
  func[1].functionData = NULL;
  func[1].function = &isSupported;

  func[2].name = (const uint8_t*) "getHelloWorld";
  func[2].functionData = NULL;
  func[2].function = &getHelloWorld;

  *functions = func;
}

void contextFinalizer(FREContext ctx)
{
  return;
}

void initializer(void** extData, FREContextInitializer* ctxInitializer, FREContextFinalizer* ctxFinalizer)
{
  *ctxInitializer = &contextInitializer;
  *ctxFinalizer = &contextFinalizer;
}

void finalizer(void* extData)
{
  return;
}
```

It seems that I have connected all the dots in the right way, but why doesn't it want to work?

Comment: Did you verify that your dll really contains those functions?

Comment: No because I don't know how to do that (I'm new at writing DLL's)

Comment: You can use something like http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html to see if your functions are visible from outside. Or you can load your dll in c++ and try to call some function.